# QGIS: Shifting ortophotos by some meters to equalize the mismatch/offset/incongruence with satellite imagery

Tags: qgis, image, digital-image-processing, offset

I got several true ortophotos from environmental authorities. These photos should serve as reference for classifying pixels of satellite records.
Though the authorities told me that the georeferencing accuracy of their photos was below half a meter, there is obviousely a total shift of about 20 meters towards east in relation to my satellite imagery. (There might be also a small north-south-offset, but obviousely not as crucial; - I have not checked yet more accurately.)

My question is now:

- Is there a way (Qgis-implemented option, plugin, python-script, customizing CRS, ...) to shift the ortophotos 20 meters back towards west (+ maybe also some meters north-south)?
  Respectively, if there were more options: Which one would you prefer?
- If possible the shift should be made by 'virtual reprojecting', i.e. without changing / recalculating the photo itself!? My project CRS is EPSG:32633

I could not find any option so far. On top, I am not a geographer (but ecologist) and quite new to QGis. I'm working with QGis-3.16 Win10.

Comment: Which CRS are the photos supposed to be in? Which DOP are you comparing them with?

Comment: The TrueDops are originally in EPSG:8687 - Slovenia 1996 / UTM 33N. The are currently (as well as supposed to be) virtually reprojected to EPSG:32633 (these CRS differ maybe a few decimeters). <br>
I want to compare the TrueDops with Sentinel-Tiles (real-reprojected to EPSG:32633, and georeferencing optimization by using landsat-imagery as base)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would trust geo-referencing of orthos more than that of satellite imagery. Especially from those with less stable orbits. Verify against OSM or similar the spatial accuracy of the orthophotos.

If you need to move the satellite imagery use the QGIS georeference functionality.

https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/georeferencing_basics.html

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Tisham.
Without going into detail:
1) My ortocorrected Sentinel-2-images match obviousely (much) more with my Landsat-8-images than the TrueDOPs do.
2) I'm creating a timeseries with a few hundreds Sentinel-records. But for classifing I need just a hand full of TrueDops.
So, for these and other reasons I would prefer to shift the TrueDOPs in this case.