# QGIS: Shifting ortophotos / rasters by a few meters in relation to their proper projection

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, move, modify-features

The following figure shows my QGIS-3.16-Canvas with an excerpt of a TrueOrtophoto (tif), with a 10-meters-point-grid in front corresponding to the pixel size of my satellite imagery. (The Ortophotos CRS is EPSG:8687 - Slovenia 1996 / UTM zone 33N, Layer-projection is EPSG:32633 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N)

[image]

Now, I want to re-georeference the the whole TrueDOP of about 1 sqare kilometer (not only the excerpt) by about 20 meters towards west and 10 meters towards north (see red arrows).

I recently had a similar question ([QGIS: Shifting ortophotos by some meters to equalize the mismatch/offset/incongruence with satellite imagery](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/404138/qgis-shifting-ortophotos-by-some-meters-to-equalize-the-mismatch-offset-incongr)), in which Tisham Dhar suggested to work with this GDAL Georeferencer tool.
I had a look at it, and if I understood this tool right: There, I load the Raster-image separately (not using it by refering to QGis-Layers). You set your source and destination Ground Control Points (GCP) in the Georeferencer-tool-canvas and run the georeferencing.

But, what I'm looking for is a solution where I can

- use the **raster-image out of my layers** and **as they are projected** there,
- use my **raster points** including the **snapping options** in order to define my GCPs.
- ideally - as I have a lot of TrueDOPs - proceed multiple layers/images at once.

That means, the tool should either work directly in the QGIS-Canvas, or may have its own canvas, but with using my QGIS-layers (with snapping functionality) as source, or ...(?)

In the end **it would enough or even better not to re-georeference the image itself, but just modifying the layer / layer-CRS** in order to display the images these few meters more west/north.

At the beginning I thought, this should be quite easy, but I am stacking ...
Anybody an idea (built-in tool, plugin, ...) for me?

By the way: I already found the *Freehand raster georeferencer plugin*, which works quite smart for some similar purposes, I think. But not for my current case. It's just freehand and cannot use both (snapping or typing in cordinates). Furtheron, it does not use the QGIS-layer-properties, but an proprietary layer-properties format discarding also the layer-CRS-information.

Edit referring to bugmenot123:

- I cannot really say the georeference ist wrong, or what exactly is wrong. The only thing I know for sure, that my TrueDOPs differ from my Sentinel imagery by an offset of about 20 m. And that my Sentinel-Imagery ist coregistered to Landsat, so the Sentinels' georeferencing accuracy should now be quite good. At least visual control suggests that: Sentinel-images match now quite well to Landsat and between each other. 
  Thus, I rather guess, that something with the TrueDOPs is wrong.
   Here an example of the offset 
   o  At the first image you see a section of the floodplain (one of my TrueDOPs), with a red line along the water channels (and a segement of the street at the right).
   o  The second figure shows the red line and in the background one of the my Sentinel images (NIR-Band), of course with according date. White (to very bright green) are water channels.
  As you will quickly see, there is an offset of about 20 meters = two pixels, mainly in an East-West-direction.

[image]
[image]

- I don't know how the TrueDOPs are georeferrenced. I got them from Italian authorities. The only thing I know at the moment is that the creation of the TrueDOPs is outsourced to a private company. The only general informations I have according to the website are: Original reference system is RDN2008-TM33NE. 
   <sub>(I already asked the authorities for the way the company is using. Unfortunatly I get no answer at the moment because of holidays. But I am not sure whether an answer will help much to me, because I expect the answer to be very specific, probably too specific for me, as I am not a geographer, but an ecologist. Anyway I don't want to rely too much on still getting an answer from there).</sub>
- Metadata: Here the layer-properties/information of one of my ecw-TrueDOPs
  [image]
- I don't know what sidecar files are. If you mean external metadata files, I do not have any. I just had a quick look at the download website, but I could not find any.

So, if I cannot figure out a specific error and correct it, I would tend to move my TrueDOPs this 20 meters freehand or by eye, respectively (I need them for classification purposes), but would like to move them all exactly the same and traceable ammount. With the mentionned freehand tool this is not possible.

Comment: This is not a full answer, thus a comment:  Before attempting your geo-referencing, I would *strongly* recommend that you establish a single CRS (using meters or feet as its unit of measure) for all of your data, and project all data to that CRS.

Comment: So is your georeference wrong or do you want to somehow override it for another reason? How is your imagery georeferenced? Embedded metadata? External sidecar files?

Comment: Try gdal_warp with tap option

Comment: Maybe isn't easy to get the image coordinates (row/col of pixel) and the georeferenced coordinates (Northing/Easting) inside the same canvas, so the georeferencer had always its own canvas for image coordinates. And is not possible (I guess) georeference two images with the same control points, because for each image, same image coordinates are related to different georeferenced ones. So I think the best we can do is perform an affine transformation (translation and maybe some rotation or uniform scale) to all the images, it can be done with `gdalwarp -ct (proj affine transformation pipeline)`

Comment: _ @bugmenot123. Thanks for your response. See edited question.

Comment: _ @vinh: I had a look at the tutorial: 
-tap =  (target aligned pixels) align the coordinates of the extent of the output file to the values of the -tr, such that the aligned extent includes the minimum extent.
As I am not familiar to reprojecting processes, I do not really understand, what inputs I have to give and what they mean, especially as -tap seems to refer to other commands. May you explain that a little bit?

Comment: _ @StuSmith: Yes of course I will do so, isn't just done yet. TrueDOPs will all get EPSG:32633 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N, same as my Sentinel tiles. (Whereas the difference between EPSG:32633 and EPSG:8687 (currently assigned to the TrueDOPs) is nearly nothing as I checked before. So I thought I could nevertheless post my questions.

Comment: _ @Gabriel: Please see my comment to vinh. Analogous issue with my moderate knowledge :-). May you also explain it a little bit?

Comment: Of course, thanks to everyone for his/her response!

Comment: Are you able to determine the X and Y shifts you need to move the orthoimage? If yes, I may have an idea that could help. It would only work if all you need is just shifts with no scaling involved.

Comment: _ @Techie_Gus: I did not go through all the TrueDOPs yet. So I cannot say, whether the shift amount is the same for all. But for the area I am currently caring about, I would try first a shift of 15 m towards west, and zero meters towards north/south. (The 20/10 m shift was just a round-about-example.). No scaling needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a new, derived through an affine transformation from a projected, CRS.

Instead of transforming the position of a layer within a reference frame, we can transform the reference frame in the reverse direction, leaving the position of the layer source dataset intact.

If we consider that by moving the layer 20 meters to the West and 10 meters to the North, we would take it where it belongs, within the EPSG:8687 system (which is the original one of the source dataset), we can create a new system that is a derivation of EPSG:8687 through an affine transformation that moves it 20 meters East and 10 meters South.

Therefore, the layer source dataset would remain in its original coordinates, but we will indicate to the applications that those coordinates must be interpreted in this new reference system.

To do that, we will use the Coordinate operation method: [EPSG:9624 (Affine parametric transformation)](https://epsg.org/coord-operation-method_9624/Affine-parametric-transformation.html) , included within a WKT definition of a CRS derived from a projected one:

```
DERIVEDPROJCRS["8687-derived",
    BASEPROJCRS["Slovenia 1996 / UTM zone 33N",
        BASEGEOGCRS["Slovenia 1996",
            DATUM["Slovenia Geodetic Datum 1996",
                ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433
                ]
            ],
            ID["EPSG",4765
            ]
        ],
        CONVERSION["UTM zone 33N",
            METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
                ID["EPSG",9807
                ]
            ],
            PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433
                ],
                ID["EPSG",8801
                ]
            ],
            PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",15,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433
                ],
                ID["EPSG",8802
                ]
            ],
            PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
                SCALEUNIT["unity",1
                ],
                ID["EPSG",8805
                ]
            ],
            PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1
                ],
                ID["EPSG",8806
                ]
            ],
            PARAMETER["False northing",0,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1
                ],
                ID["EPSG",8807
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    DERIVINGCONVERSION["Affine",
        METHOD["Affine parametric transformation",
            ID["EPSG",9624
            ]
        ],
        PARAMETER["A0",20,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1
            ],
            ID["EPSG",8623
            ]
        ],
        PARAMETER["A1",1,
            SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1
            ],
            ID["EPSG",8624
            ]
        ],
        PARAMETER["A2",0,
            SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1
            ],
            ID["EPSG",8625
            ]
        ],
        PARAMETER["B0",-10,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1
            ],
            ID["EPSG",8639
            ]
        ],
        PARAMETER["B1",0,
            SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1
            ],
            ID["EPSG",8640
            ]
        ],
        PARAMETER["B2",1,
            SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1
            ],
            ID["EPSG",8641
            ]
        ]
    ],
    CS[Cartesian,2
    ],
    AXIS["(E)",east,
        ORDER[1
        ],
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1
        ]
    ],
    AXIS["(N)",north,
        ORDER[2
        ],
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1
        ]
    ]
]
```

A0 and B0 parameters are the translations. A1, A2, B1 and B2 parameters are the (2D) scaled rotations.

Add a custom CRS from the above WKT definition in QGIS and **Set** (do not project) the new CRS to the layers to be adjusted.

You can change the values and re-set the CRS of the layers any times. When you're done, you can export the layers to other well-known reference system.

Comment: Wow, oookeeey , I had just a quick look for now. Into detail I will go tomorrow. Thanks very much so far!!!! You will hear of me of course again!

Comment: Only one question at the moment: As my project CRS is EPSG:32633 (not EPSG:8687 Slovenia 1996). Can I change the base CRS easily to 32633?

Comment: The source data (the file 04906106.ecw) of the layer is referenced to EPSG: 8687, so you can move it within that frame, or move that frame. You can reproject those files to another system and define a CRS derived from the new reference.

Comment: In the WKT string, replace the BASEPROJCRS node with the PROJCRS node of the new CRS definition.

Comment: _ @Gabriel, I tried your affine EPSG:8687. Looks good. Thanks
So, I edited my EPSG:32633 to an affine one with 20 m west and zero north. And it looks also good.
But as I am generally quite new to GIS and, anyway, not too familiar in detail with this WKT stuff: Do I have nothing to change in the  _DERIVINGCONVERSION_ part in comparison to your 8687-affine-CRS? Or, may you check my trial at all, whether its right or in the right order, respectively? I would post both, normal 32633-string and my customized one as an separate answer in the next minutes.

Comment: In the DERIVINGCONVERSION node, change just the parameters of the affine transformation that you want to apply: A0 = 20, B0 = 0 for translations. A1 and B2 = 1, A2 and B1 = 0 for not scale nor rotation. Both EPSG:32633 and EPSG:8687 are the same projection, just from different datums. Don't expect big changes between them.

Comment: _ @Gabriel: Yes, I already realized that there is just a minimal difference between them both. My concern was more: As the CONVERSION and the DERIVINGCONV seem somehow to be built by several EPSGs (I never really dealt with this stuff), I was wondering whether I could simply use your/the same EPSG:8687-DERIVINGCONV-params , when altering now EPSG:32633. At that moment I loaded up my solution (as separate answer). May you have a look?

Comment: There are EPSG codes for any part of a WKT string: the base geographic reference, the projection method, the parameter definitions, the conversion method. Don't worry about them. You can apply an affine transformation to any projected reference system in this way.

Comment: To summarize / understand your last comments: 

Method 1: I could keep the current internal CRS (8687) of my trueDOPs and assign my affine-32633-layer-CRS directly to it. Method 2, which would generally be better: First transforming the TrueDOP itself to a new internal CRS (in my case 32633) and then assigning my affine-36233-layer-CRS. But, as in this case both projections only differ by date, I hadn't really to worry if using Method 1.  - Right? And thanks for your patience!

Comment: Don't use method 1. Difference is not a date, it is a geographic base reference system. Different ellipsoid involved, and must be defined a datum transformation between WGS84 and Slovenia 1996 reference frames. Method 2 is the way to do it.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks, I'll never run out of work :-). Besides that: As we in the end actually treated two questions throughout the whole thread (Warping the image itself AND customizing the layer CRS), I would suggest to divide the thread by shifting the whole customizing-the-layer-projection sequence into a separate question, if you agree of course. But I don't know how, except from deleting the answers/comments and paste them again. Thus, I could give you also "best answer" twice. What do you think?

Comment: Your question is good and has good answers. You can edit your answer to explain your solution to the task and accept it as the best. Seems ok to me. Success and regards!

Comment: Ok, so we'll keep it as before. And of course yours was the best. Thaaaanks

Comment: _@Gabriel. After all, there is still an issue left. Works principally fine: I reprojected my images to EPSG:32633, an then assigned the +10/20meters-custom/affine/derived-EPSG:32633 to the according layers. My problem is now, that each time when I start a new QGIS session the custom-CRS-layer-information is lost and reset to normal EPSG:32633. As both, the normal and the affine version end up with `ID["EPSG",32633]]` --> Might this be the reason? If yes, may I use an individuall ID, e.g. 32633a, for the custom version?

Comment: _@Gabriel BTW: In the layer-CRS-selection menu the Autority ID for the normal CRS is EPSG:32633 and for the custom one ist USER:10000x

Comment: Hi! Custom projections are saved as USER Authority in the QGIS CRSes database. You can't use EPSG Authority to those definitions. GDAL/OGR don't fully implemented the extension for WKT2 representations (this derived projection was not possible in WKT1 format), so he CRS can't be saved in the layer datasource yet. Until that, the best practice is reproject the layers to an EPSG authority CRS and work there.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with 'was not possible in WKT1 format'? Also your last sentence: What is/means an EPSG authority CRS? And if it should mean the custom CRS: Do you mean to reproject the layer (what I did) or to reproject the layer source with the custom CRS. - Sorry, I don't knwow whether having told you before: I am an ecologist, not a geographer and very new to all this projection, CRS and WKT 1 and 2 stuff :-)

Comment: Hi @Gabriel again. As this thread guess is long enough I opened a new question onto this issue: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408683/custom-derived-crs-by-affine-transformation-from-epsg32633-setting-as-layer-cr

Comment: Hi. I will answer your other question later. For now, the "DERIVEDPROJCRS" was standarized in WKT2 format, in WKT1 format this CRS definition was just not possible. For compatibility reasons, we can't yet store only a WKT2 format CRS definition with the dataset, so the idea is set the CRS for the layer and export it to a well known EPSG CRS. EPSG authority means for any CRS that have an EPSG code, that is it is registered at EPSG.org database.

Answer (score 2):

We can perform the same affine transformation to all the images.

To create b.tif, wich is moved 20 m to the West and 10 m to the North, from a.tif, in its own coordinates reference system:

`gdalwarp -ct "+proj=affine +xoff=-20 +yoff=10" a.tif b.tif`

It can also be done in QGIS from the GDAL `Warp (reproject)` processing algortihm, including the `-ct "(proj transformation type string)"` additional command-line parameter:

[image: 1]

The affine transformation can include rotations and independent scale for each dimension: https://proj.org/operations/transformations/affine.html

About gdalwarp: https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html

Comment: Great, this sounds in any case to be a solution!
But, would it be possible as well, analoguos to your warp method, just to modify the layer-assigned CRS? What I mean is to change the 'EPSG:32633-WGS84/TMzone33N' into a custom 'EPSG:32633-WGS84/TMzone33N-**+xoff=-20+yoff=10**'-CRS? So that i get just a 'warped view' of the image instead of modifying the image itself. I hope you unterstand what I mean. Thus, I would save the recalculation of all my TrueDOPs.
I hope you won't despair of me :-)

Comment: I understand. Yes, it is possible. I need to test if it works.

Answer (score 1):

This is my result for the EPSG:32633-affine-CRS.

First, as you last comments were not absolutely clear for me / to avoid misunderstandings:

- The internal EPSG of my TrueDops is EPSG:8687 (or to be exact, they are automatically loaded to QGIS as 8687. So, to be honest I don't know whether the TrueDOPs have an internal base CRS).
- I want to view the TrueDOPs as EPSG:32633 (= my project CRS), with the additional shift of some meters.

Here my EPSG:32633-affine-CRS, in this case 20 m towards west, and **0**, not 10 m towards north. (The normal 32633-string you will find afterwards.)

```
DERIVEDPROJCRS["32633-derived",
BASEPROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 33N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",15,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]]],
DERIVINGCONVERSION["Affine",
    METHOD["Affine parametric transformation",
        ID["EPSG",9624]],
    PARAMETER["A0",20,
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
        ID["EPSG",8623]],
    PARAMETER["A1",1,
        SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],
        ID["EPSG",8624]],
    PARAMETER["A2",0,
        SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],
        ID["EPSG",8625]],
    PARAMETER["B0",0,
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
        ID["EPSG",8639]],
    PARAMETER["B1",0,
        SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],
        ID["EPSG",8640]],
    PARAMETER["B2",1,
        SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],
        ID["EPSG",8641]]],
CS[Cartesian,2],
    AXIS["(E)",east,
        ORDER[1],
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    AXIS["(N)",north,
        ORDER[2],
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
USAGE[
    SCOPE["unknown"],
    AREA["World - N hemisphere - 12°E to 18°E - by country"],
    BBOX[0,12,84,18]],
ID["EPSG",32633]]
```

Here the normal 32633-string out of QGis:

```
PROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N",
BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]],
CONVERSION["UTM zone 33N",
    METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
        ID["EPSG",9807]],
    PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        ID["EPSG",8801]],
    PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",15,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        ID["EPSG",8802]],
    PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
        SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
        ID["EPSG",8805]],
    PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
        ID["EPSG",8806]],
    PARAMETER["False northing",0,
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
        ID["EPSG",8807]]],
CS[Cartesian,2],
    AXIS["(E)",east,
        ORDER[1],
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    AXIS["(N)",north,
        ORDER[2],
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
USAGE[
    SCOPE["unknown"],
    AREA["World - N hemisphere - 12°E to 18°E - by country"],
    BBOX[0,12,84,18]],
ID["EPSG",32633]]
```

What do you mean?

Comment: gdalinfo shows that EPSG:8687 is the reference for the data source, most probably it is defined internally. If you want to reference it to EPSG:32633, just reproject it. Next, you can assign the 32633-affine-CRS to the reprojected layer. Since the only difference between both (8687 and 32633) CRSes is the datum, you can assign any of them to the layer, but it is better if you reproject the data source before to assign the derived CRS. If you want to see differences to a better understand, reproject the datasource to a really different projection and try to assign the derived CRS to it.

Comment: "gdalinfo shows that EPSG:8687...."

That's interesting. Where can I see this information? (My layer-properties' information shows only the assigned projection.)

Comment: I'm sorry, was confused about the screenshot. Just run the gdalinfo tool to the source data file, not the layer.