# Custom-derived CRS by affine transformation from EPSG:32633: Setting as layer-CRS works only for current QGis-session. Information lost after restart

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, layers, epsg, affine-transformation

I am working with QGIS 3.16, Win10. 
 With help of another SE-user I created several derived CRS by an affine transformation from EPSG:32633 CRS (see below) in order to shift some related layers a couple of meters. The sources of my layer sets are polygone-shp-vector-files and TrueDop-gtiff-raster-files with 'normal' EPSG:32633 as internal CRS. In case of the here given example the shifting values are 20 m towards west and 0 meters towards north. But for other layer sets there are 3 further custom CRS with a shift of 14/6, 10/8 6/10 meters towards west/north. 
 Assigning my custom CRS to my layers works principally fine: The respective layers are shown with an offset of 20 m towards west in comparison to 'normal' EPSG:32633.
But if I close QGIS and open my project in a new QGIS-session at the next morning, the layers are reset to the 'normal' EPSG:32633-position on the Canvas, though the layer properties show the right custom CRS (see image, red underlined). But in turn, if going further into the CRS-selection menue, the 'normal' EPSG:32633 is marked to be set.

[image]

So I would have to reassign the costum CRS to the respective layers each time when runnning a new QGIS-session!

Anybody an idea what the reason could be, or how this could be solved?

Here the derived CRS string:

```
DERIVEDPROJCRS["32633-derived",
BASEPROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 33N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",15,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]]],
DERIVINGCONVERSION["Affine",
    METHOD["Affine parametric transformation",
        ID["EPSG",9624]],
    PARAMETER["A0",20,
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
        ID["EPSG",8623]],
    PARAMETER["A1",1,
        SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],
        ID["EPSG",8624]],
    PARAMETER["A2",0,
        SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],
        ID["EPSG",8625]],
    PARAMETER["B0",0,
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
        ID["EPSG",8639]],
    PARAMETER["B1",0,
        SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],
        ID["EPSG",8640]],
    PARAMETER["B2",1,
        SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],
        ID["EPSG",8641]]],
CS[Cartesian,2],
    AXIS["(E)",east,
        ORDER[1],
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    AXIS["(N)",north,
        ORDER[2],
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
USAGE[
    SCOPE["unknown"],
    AREA["World - N hemisphere - 12°E to 18°E - by country"],
    BBOX[0,12,84,18]],
ID["EPSG",32633]]
```

Comment: If the shift is only and exactly 20 m to the west, you could run the `translate geometry` tool once and be done with it?

Comment: Yes and No, I have four different shifting types. Only for the first set of layers the shift is 20/0 meters (towards west/north). The other layers need to be shifted 14/6, 10/8 and 6/10. Would your approach work then as well?

Comment: According to the [documentation page on translate](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=translate#translate) it should work as you require it to - but have a look yourself.

Comment: I had a look yet, - x and y is no problem. But the tool only adresses to vector data. In my case each of my layer sets consist of one polygone shp-layer and some raster layers (TrueDOPS) which should be shifted by the same values. I cannot find any translate-geom counterpart for rasters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't use the `ID["EPSG",32633]` attribute for the `DERIVEDPROJCRS[]` node, because it is the identification of the WGS84 / UTM Zone 33N projected CRS.
QGIS 3.18 does not accept it.

Try with the following definition:

```
DERIVEDPROJCRS["32633-derived",
  BASEPROJCRS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 33N",
    BASEGEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]],
    CONVERSION["UTM zone 33N",
        METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
            ID["EPSG",9807]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8801]],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",15,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
            SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
            ID["EPSG",8805]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]]],
  DERIVINGCONVERSION["Affine",
    METHOD["Affine parametric transformation",
        ID["EPSG",9624]],
    PARAMETER["A0",20,
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
        ID["EPSG",8623]],
    PARAMETER["A1",1,
        SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],
        ID["EPSG",8624]],
    PARAMETER["A2",0,
        SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],
        ID["EPSG",8625]],
    PARAMETER["B0",0,
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
        ID["EPSG",8639]],
    PARAMETER["B1",0,
        SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],
        ID["EPSG",8640]],
    PARAMETER["B2",1,
        SCALEUNIT["coefficient",1],
        ID["EPSG",8641]]],
  CS[Cartesian,2],
    AXIS["(E)",east,
        ORDER[1],
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    AXIS["(N)",north,
        ORDER[2],
        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]]]
```

You will be able to close QGIS and reopen it. Layers (both vector and raster) will keep it.

We cannot yet assign the custom CRS to the source data. The standardization of the format is recent and many applications could not read them.

As far as possible, export the layers to EPSG:32633 or another CRS once they are located where you think they belong.

Comment: Hey Gabriel, works perfectly. CRS-information will be kept when restarting QGIS. Thanks very much.
I hope I got you last sentence right: I assign the modified CRS to my layers that contain sources (tif or shp) with the standard CRS, then exporting the layers with current layer extent, but standard CRS. So the new SHPs/Tiffs now have standard CRS **AND** the intended extent.  I work on with the new files and with the benifit of never having problems with unstandardized strings. Right?

Comment: You are welcome. That's right. It is the equivalent of doing a translation of the source data, but with the flexibility of adjusting the translation parameters by setting a custom coordinate system to display the results before performing the transformation.